# How to make Google Earth offline?

Tags: google-earth

I want to run Google Earth offline. I've read [this](https://superuser.com/questions/102187/how-can-i-run-google-earth-offline) question, but I have no time navigating all the places. Is there any ways to do it?

Comment: Read the next article about Google Maps Offline: https://support.google.com/maps/answer/6291838?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en

Comment: @F.Rahamim I'm asking about Google Earth.

Comment: So try this one https://support.google.com/earth/answer/168344?hl=en&topic=2376075&ctx=topic

Comment: @F.Rahamim I tried. This doesn't work. All of it is just a viewer of Google Earth and cannot work offline.